# Material ui grid change content direction to row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to material ui and i created a grid that contains 2 components,an autocomplet and a button.these 2 are displayed one below the other,so i want to algin them in a row. Here's how my code looks like:

```
<Grid item sm={4} xs={12} direction="row"><Autocomplete/><button/><Grid>
```

I tried direction="row" but it doesn't work.
I would appreciate your help

Comment: Please also add your child component' code implementations so we can help easily.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand?. I have a grid container with multiple grids inside,this grid is one of them containing a button and an autocomplet,they are displayed one above the other,i want to make them side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use grid system same as technical [documentation](https://next.material-ui.com/components/grid/#fluid-grids) example shown below,

```
export default function BasicGrid() {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={8}>
        <Item>Autocomplete Here</Item>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Item>Button Here</Item>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[Here is working sandbox example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-2h7i4?file=/demo.js:342-592)

Comment: I have a problem of spacing, there is non,how could i fix it?